# Posting Multiple Headers with Flurl

Tags: c#, flurl

Hi I'm using Flurl and I need to set multiple headers for the post and the documentation on the site states to do await url.WithHeaders(new { h1 = "foo", h2 = "bar" }).GetJsonAsync();

I'm not sure what this means, what is H1, H2 ?

I'm trying to set Headers "API-VERSION:21" and "Authorization: askjdalksdjlaksjdlaksjd";

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use documentation (a very beautiful one): https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-http/

```
// one: 
await url.WithHeader("someheader", "foo").GetJsonAsync();

// multiple: 
await url.WithHeaders(new { h1 = "foo", h2 = "bar" }).GetJsonAsync();
```

`h1` and `h2` are names of headers, and `"foo"` and `"bar"` are values.
As you can see you may also use call `.WithHeader("headerName", "headerValue")` in your case:

```
.WithHeader("API-VERSION", "21")
.WithHeader("Authorization", "askjdalksdjlaksjdlaksjd")
```

In other words chain calls to send multiple headers.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion about `WithHeaders` looks correct. But looking at the code it doesn't look like `WithHeader` can be chained.

[image]